# Change JavaScript object value with this.id

Tags: jquery, object, addition

I want to write a code which will add 1 to the object value on button click where button ID is the same as name in object (I will write function to dynamically add new positions in object). I hope you understand what I am talking about. I'm not English native speaker.. :)

I have this code (in first alert i want to get "99" and "100" in second **but it doesn't work when I use this.id**):

```
var obj = {mybuttonid: 99};
$('button').click(function () {
alert(obj.this.id);
obj.this.id++;
alert(obj.this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want

```js
var obj = {mybuttonid: 99};
$('button').click(function () {
    alert(obj[this.id]);
    obj[this.id]++;
    alert(obj[this.id]);
});
```

```js
var obj = {
  "foo": 99,
  "bar": 50
};
$('button').click(function () {
  alert(obj[this.id]);
  obj[this.id]++;
  alert(obj[this.id]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="foo">99</button>
<button id="bar">50</button>
```